# How do I compute the entropy of the beta distribution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried

```
Expectation[-q*Log[q], q \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[a, b]]
```

and got

```
(a (HarmonicNumber[a] - HarmonicNumber[a + b]))/(a + b)
```

(I get the same result using integration.)
This seems pretty different from the expression in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution),
even after substituting the identity (mentioned at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) that `H[n] = gamma + PolyGamma[0,n+1]`, where `gamma` is Euler's constant and `PolyGamma[0, n+1] = Digamma[n+1]`.

Any ideas which identity I'm missing?

Kevin

P.S. I trust the Wikipedia answer, I have seen this result before, but I want to re-derive it with *Mathematica* as a sanity check, before I go on to derive other expressions of interest.

Comment: You could plot the Wikipedia result and yours for a number of parameter values to see whether they might be the same after all.

Answer (score 20):

Your definition of entropy is incorrect. It's $E(-\ln(P(x)))$, with $E$ the expectation operator and $P$ the probability mass function of the random variable $x$. I believe you may have been mixing up a few things.

The formal definition of the expectation is $E(x)=\int{x P(x)dx}$. I assume that you had this in mind and you further confused your random variable $q$ with its PDF to write

```
Expectation[-q*Log[q], q \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[a, b]]
```

for the entropy.

Instead this should have been:

```
Expectation[-Log[PDF[BetaDistribution[a, b], q]], q \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[a, b]]
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't prod Mathematica to show the equality between Wikipedia's result and this formal definition symbolically. However, numerically it works out quite well.

This is Wikipedia's version:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In Mathematica terms:

```
Ψ[n_] := HarmonicNumber[n - 1] - EulerGamma

entropyBeta[a_, b_] = 
  FullSimplify[Log[Beta[a, b]] - (a - 1) Ψ[a] - (b - 1) Ψ[b] + (a + b - 2) Ψ[a + b],     
    Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}];
```

Comparing:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[entropyBeta[a, b], {b, 0.01, 5}],
  DiscretePlot[
    Quiet@
    NExpectation[-Log[PDF[BetaDistribution[a, b], q]], q \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[a, b]], 
   {b, 0.1, 5, .1}]
  ],
 {a, 0.01, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, they match very well.

Comment: One spurious bracket removed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist = BetaDistribution[a, b];
```

The constraints on the parameters are

```
assume = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist];
```

The integral needs a little help:

```
(entropy[BetaDistribution[a, b]] = Assuming[assume && 0 < x < 1,
     Integrate[
       -Log[PDF[dist, x]]*PDF[dist, x] // Simplify //
        FunctionExpand, {x, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify] /.
    Gamma[x_ + y_] :> Gamma[x]*Gamma[y]/Beta[x, y]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]