# Entropy[...] doesn't calculate the entropy of a probability distribution? What does it do?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I know the definition of entropy of a probability distribution:

$$H = - \sum_i p_i \log p_i $$

So for example, in a Bernoulli distribution with $p = 0.2$, $1-p=0.8$, the entropy is $0.5$. However, in Mathematica

```
 Entropy[{0.2,0.8}]
```

returns `Log[2]`. So either the Mathematica has a bug, or I don't understand what it is that `Entropy[...]` calculates in Mathematica. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: try `N@Entropy@RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.2], 100000]`

Comment: I have discuss this problem on community
I think like you that is not the Shannon entropy, but the Ashby entropy
A. Dauphiné

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Okay, that gives the number I want. Care to explain why?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius If I want to calculate the entropy of a probability distribution, I have to generate a large sample from it first. Seems inefficient.

Comment: @becko, it's just what the function does, estimate the entropy from samples. Like `Mean` or `Variance`. However, those 2 also do the proper symbolic thing when passed a distribution and `Entropy` doesn't. But you can do it by hand, e.g, `entropy[dist_] := 
 Expectation[-Log[PDF[dist, \[FormalX]]], \[FormalX] \[Distributed] 
   dist]` ?

Comment: `Entropy[list]` is the same thing as `Total[(-# Log[#] &) /@ (Values@Counts[list]/Length[list])]`.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems Mathematica's `Entropy` is equivalent to the following code (at least for lists of symbols and strings):

```
entropy[list_List] :=
 With[{p = Tally[list][[All, 2]]/Length[list]},
  -p.Log[p]
  ]

entropy[str_String] :=
 With[{p = Tally[Characters@str][[All, 2]]/StringLength[str]},
  -p.Log[p]
  ]
```

You can try this on the examples on the `Entropy` help page to see the result is the same:

```
entropy[{0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1}] == Entropy[{0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1}]
(* True *)

entropy["A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"] == 
 Entropy["A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]
(* True *)
```

This means that Mathematica calculates entropy using `Log` base e, which is called [nat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(unit)) entropy. With a choice of 2 for the base of the `Log` you get the Shannon entropy and with 10 as base you end up with the Hartley entropy.

Comment: Isn't the Hartley entropy the max-entropy rather than a base 10 entropy?

Comment: Just follow the link in the answer and you’ll see that the Hartley entropy is just the nat entropy up to a constant factor.

Comment: Have a look at [Hartley or max-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#Hartley_or_max-entropy). Apparently base 10 refers to the [hartley logarithmic unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_(unit)). IMHO using the same name for both is very prone to confusion.

Answer (score 8):

[Borrowing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35489/9490) from Sjoerd C. de Vries,(noticed this also matches rojolalalalalalalalalalalalala's comment),  you don't need to generate a list of random number in order to calculate the entropy of a distribution, but you do need to if you want to use [`Entropy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entropy.html).

```
Expectation[-Log[PDF[BernoulliDistribution[.2], q]], 
 q \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[.2]]
(* 0.500402 *)
```

This matches the formula for the entropy of the Bernoulli distribution,

[image]

```
-.2 Log[.2] - .8 Log[.8]
(* 0.500402 *)
```

Comment: And what does `Entropy` do, exactly? That was my original question.

Comment: Based on the comment above by Belisarius, I assume it creates a distribution function from the input list and calculates the entropy from it, but as you can see, the documentation is minimal

Answer (score 5):

The `Entropy` function takes a list of numbers and gets the proportion of values for each unique number and applies the entropy formula you show using those proportions ($p_i$).

For a binomial distribution:

```
(* Sample size *)
n = 97 

(* Take random sample *)
x = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1, 0.5], n]
(* {0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,
0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1} *)

(* Calculate entropy *)
Entropy[x]
```

[image: Entropy result]

```
(* Totals for each unique value *)
x1 = Total[x]
(* 41 *)
x0 = n - Total[x]
(* 56 *)
```

For a random sample from a normal distribution where all values are unique:

```
n = 97
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n]
Entropy[x]
(* Log[97] *)
```

Comment: Great! So OP would get `Log[2]` as an answer from any list with 2 unique values.

Comment: @JasonB   If the list had a length of 2 and the two numbers were not equal to each other, then, yes, the OP would get `Log[2]`.  But otherwise the number obtained would be dependent on the frequencies of the two unique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The entropy of a normalized list of probabilities is returned by

```
entropy[prob_List]/;Total[prob]==1 := With[{q=prob/.{0->1,0.0->1}}, -q.Log[q] ]
```

This expression avoids 0*Log[0] = Indeterminate results from probability distributions as e.g. {0.0, 0.2, 0.8}.