# Entropy of a probability distribution (symbolically)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

How can I compute the entropy of a probability distribution in Mathematica?

For example,

```
Entropy[NormalDistribution[m, s]]
```

does not work, because `Entropy` [does not compute the entropy of a probability distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105497/534).

On the other hand,

```
Expectation[Log@PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x], Distributed[x, NormalDistribution[m, s]]]
```

takes forever to run, and I don't think it will give an answer. So it would seem Mathematica does not have symbolic rules in place to compute entropies of probability distributions.

Is there a better way to get the formula of the entropy of probability distributions in Mathematica?

Comment: Thank you for your effort: We now have a rather concise definition for `forever` which appears to be around `160 secs`. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timing can be improved with simplification with assumptions:

```
exp = Expand[
   FullSimplify[-Log[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x]], 
    Assumptions -> {{m, x, s} ∈ Reals, s > 0}]];
Integrate[
  exp PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x], {x, -∞, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {{m, x, s} ∈ Reals, s > 0}] // Timing
```

yields:

```
{2.09375, 1/2 (1 + Log[2 π s^2])}
```

See comment by @gwr below.

```
Expectation
```

yields better performance on simplified expression (as 'expected')...too bad I didn't think to use it :(

Comment: Using `Expectation` here I do get an even more impressive timing, e.g. `Expectation[ exp, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m, s], 
  Assumptions -> {{m, x, s} \[Element] Reals, 
    s > 0}] // RepeatedTiming` will give `0.0018` secs on my machine.

Comment: @gwr yes I should have tried. It is 'expected' (pardon the pun) given exp is just a constant + scaled mean and scaled second moment, i.e.easy to calculate. Thank you for pointing it out:)

Answer (score 6):

Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Then, the way we solve this in Chapter 1 of *Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica* (free download of book available [here](http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html)) is to find $E[-log(f)]$:

[image]

... which uses the *mathStatica* `Expect` function, and takes about 6 seconds to evaluate on my Mac in 11.2.

I was surprised at the OP's suggestion that:

```
Expectation[Log@PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x], 
Distributed[x, NormalDistribution[m, s]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

... does not evaluate. When I tried it, it does evaluate, but it takes about 160 seconds to return the equivalent:

> {161.93, 1/2 (-1 - Log[2 [Pi] s^2])}

... on the same computer in v11.1.1 and about 80 seconds under 11.2.

Comment: I let it run some more time and it evaluated here too, so my statement was inaccurate. However, it takes a very long time.

Answer (score 6):

I was just recently dealing with this, so I thought I should leave this line here for anyone who winds up finding this question too:

```
ShannonEntropy[dist_?DistributionParameterQ] :=
  -Expectation[LogLikelihood[dist,{x}], x \[Distributed] dist]

AbsoluteTiming[ShannonEntropy[NormalDistribution[]]]
(* {0.122426, 1/2 (1 + Log[2] + Log[\[Pi]])} *)
```

Additionally, a slightly more thorough version is available [here](https://github.com/K-a-n-u/ShannonEntropy).